# Inserting default relationship instance during Core Data custom migration

Tags: ios, macos, core-data

**TLD;DR:** *During Core Data migration, how to properly insert a default instance for the new relationship?*

I've added a new required relationship on my Core Data model. During the custom migration process, I want to create a default value for that migration for old entities.
However, when the migration finishes, I can't retrieve those new objects.

**Here's how I set up a Relationship Mapping expression:**

`FUNCTION($entityPolicy, "migrate_createDefaultAudioMixWithSource:manager:error:" , $source, $manager)`
[image]

**Here's my custom migration policy:**

```swift
class MigrationPolicy_11To12: NSEntityMigrationPolicy {
        
    @objc(migrate_createDefaultAudioMixWithSource:manager:error:)
    func migrate_createDefaultAudioMix(source sInstance: NSManagedObject, manager: NSMigrationManager) throws -> NSManagedObject {
        let newObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "TrackAudioMixParametersEntity",
                                                                into: manager.destinationContext)
        newObject.setValue(UUID(), forKey: "id")
        
        return newObject
    }
}
```

The migration is successfull and the new object is indeed added. However, when I try to access its properties, Core Data logging an error and returns just `nils`.

`let _ = track.audioMixParameters.id // returns nil and logs error`

> CoreData: fault: entityForObjectID failed to retrieve an NSSQLEntity for objectID 0xb3078b67b6cedaf5 x-coredata://D09D6224-6549-43A2-A7AC-01F40D231C89/TrackAudioMixParametersEntity/p1
>
> CoreData: fault: _sqlCoreLookupSQLEntityForEntityDescription failed to return a result for objectID 0xb3078b67b6cedaf5

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work but when I've done similar migrations I've used `createDestinationInstances(forSource:in:manager:)`. I don't know if that's better than what you're trying to do though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I'm using multiple `Configurations` of my Core Data model. Turns out I forgot to add the new Entity to the `Configuration` that I was using to open the Store.

So it basically had nothing to do with the migration.

I wish Core Data would have logged more meaningful info in such case :-\